# How can I write a virtual keyboard for the linux console?

Tags: linux, usb

I'd like some way to send keyboard input to a linux machine without a keyboard. I'd like this input to be accepted in any linux console, and in xmbc.

One idea I had would be to write some type of virtual USB keyboard that would send the input to in that way, but maybe this is over complicating it.

Basically what I'm looking for is Synergy without X (and with XMBC)

Anyone have suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a user space driver to inject events into kernel.. so you can ssh into your linux box, run the driver and inject the keypresses you type.. so it will be as if there is a physical keyboard attached and would work with all programs. [This](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) gives good info on how to write user space drivers... if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, this program [TermKeyboard](https://github.com/chaitu236/TermKeyboard) does exactly that.

Disclaimer: I wrote the program

Answer (score -1):

there is a keyboard for fbcon on sourceforge. to com;ile it you must add string.h include
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tabletvk/?source=dlp

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**